# Why would code explicitly call a static method via a null pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, static-members, undefined-behavior, dereference

I've seen code like this in a couple of old projects:

```
class Class {
    static void Method() {}
};

((Class*)0)->Method();
```

This code contains undefined behavior because it includes dereferencing a null pointer (no matter what happens afterwards). It really makes no sense - the cast is there to feed the type name to the compiler and whoever wrote the code above could have written this instead:

```
Class::Method();
```

and the latter would be okay.

Why would anyone write the former code? Is it a known idiom from some good old days or what?

Comment: And here I thought it was just Java that allowed calling class members via instance references. Huh.

Comment: There is another interesting similar thing. Even if the method is not static, if you don't use `this` or use any fields from class it wont produce IllegalAccess error.
like `class C {void f() { cout << "something"; }} C* instance = nullptr; instance->f();`

Comment: What makes you think a null pointer will be _dereferenced_ by this code? Why would x->staticMethod() dereference x?

Comment: I suspect this kind of thing comes from macros that can be used with regular or static methods.

Comment: I am not certain the call in itself is strictly doing any "dereferencing". Though that might happen in the function itself.

Comment: It's kind of like the fake dereferencing in the `offsetof()` macro that people wrote before it was added to the language.

Comment: It's obviously a bad thing to do - my best guess is that originally `Method` was not static (but didn't access any instance data) and someone used this hack to invoke it. Later someone else realised that `Method` needed to be static and changed it, but didn't fix all the places that it was being called from.

Comment: It's probably a very bad attempt to mimicate `abort()`.

Comment: @gnasher729: The Standard says `a->b` is equivalent to `(*a).b` and `*a` is dereferencing.

Comment: @40two: This will likely never call abort. Most likely it just works. I cannot imagine how the C++ runtime would call `abort()` from there.

Comment: Its far more common to see a null pointer *variable* used with this. Ex: VC++ DevCon 1999, DonBox touted, `CComObject<YourClass>* pObj = NULL; HRESULT hr = pObj->CreateInstance(&pObj);` "You know you can do that, right?" Well, [**read this**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3498473/1322972) and decide which side of the fence you reside on. Its clear where Don hangs out.

Comment: @sharptooth it won't call `abort()` it will break the program intentionally.

Comment: I met a developer (now manager) with 20 years' commercial C++ experience who wrote this, then was entirely baffled as to why the rest of us told him, during a very fortunate code review, that it was wrong. Seemingly hadn't even heard of `::` notation, and became very confused. -.-

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Static member functions were added into C++ in 1989, in [Release 2.0](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/c_plus_plus/cfront/release_2.0/doc/ReleaseNotes.pdf) of the AT&T C++ Language System (pre-standardisation).  Prior to that, the `static` keyword could not be used to declare static member functions, so code authors used workarounds, principally the one you have observed of indirecting a null pointer.

In the [Selected Readings](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/c_plus_plus/cfront/release_2.0/doc/SelectedReadings.pdf) accompanying version 2.0 of the AT&T C++ Language System, in section 1-22, Stroustrup writes:

> It was also observed that nonportable code, such as:
>
> ```
> ((X*)0)->f();
> ```
>
> was used to simulate static member functions. This trick is a time bomb because sooner or later someone will make an `f()` that is used this way `virtual` and the call will fail horribly because there is no `X` object at address zero. Even where `f()` is not virtual such calls will fail under some implementations of dynamic linking.

Your code was written to compile under Cfront 1.0 or by someone who was not aware at the time of the addition of static member functions to the language.

The annotation of the member function with `static` is indeed a puzzle, as *Cheers and hth. - Alf* has observed; Cfront 1.0 would have rejected that code with:

```
error:  member Method() cannot be static
```

so it cannot have been there initially. I think *Potatoswatter* is most likely correct; `static` was added at a later date to document and enforce the static method attribute of `Method`, once a C++ 2.0 compiler could be guaranteed to be available, but without the calling code being updated. To confirm this you'd need to interview the original programmer(s) or at least examine source control history (if any exists).

Comment: Why doesn't Stroustrup mention the more egregious problem of undefined behavior? He argues with implementation details.

Comment: @usr It goes without saying that the crash *in practice* is due to undefined behavior *in theory*.

Comment: @Potatoswatter No matter what f does, an optimizing compiler can treat the call as unreachable. This is frequently being done. A crash is not at all the only practical consequence. Deletion of code is another. That's why arguing with implementation details is inferior to just pointing out UB. The failure modes follow from the presence of UB.

Comment: @usr: Stroustrup couldn't argue about undefined behavior pre 1998, such as for code before 1989 (this code), because that would be meaningless. The language was only informally and partially defined then, by his book "The C++ Programming Language".

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Likely the client (function call) code is cruftier, and the library (class definition) was updated with `static` after it was introduced. Or, it's the product of two programmers, one of whom was anachronistic.