# c++ access static members using null pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, static-members, nullptr

Recently tried the following program and it compiles, runs fine and produces expected output instead of any runtime error.

```
#include <iostream>
class demo
{
    public:
        static void fun()
        {
            std::cout<<"fun() is called\n";
        }
        static int a;
};
int demo::a=9;
int main()
{
    demo* d=nullptr;
    d->fun();
    std::cout<<d->a;
    return 0;
}
```

If an uninitialized pointer is used to access class and/or struct members behaviour is undefined, but why it is allowed to access static members using null pointers also. Is there any harm in my program?

Comment: `Is there any harm in my program?` It is still UB.

Comment: Undefined behavior does not mean that the code is required to crash; rather it means that anything at all is allowed to happen, the result is undefined. That is, the code could appear to work fine and as expected, it could crash, it could appear to run fine but give you the wrong result, anything at all.

Comment: Voted to reopen; the linked question addresses non-static members, not static ones.

Comment: @T.C.: The answer's the same, though, isn't it?

Comment: @T.C. Alright, this one then? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498444/c-static-const-access-through-a-null-pointer

Comment: this is an interesting question - it compiles cleanly with no warnings, it calls the correct function. Is it valid syntax? Forget that d is null, what if d is valid pointer. It is surprising to see d->f() where f is a static function

Comment: @Barry I'm not quite convinced. After the usual transformation for `->`, the object expression is `*d`, but for static members it's just evaluated and discarded. This is basically http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#232; also http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#315

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325555/c-static-member-method-call-on-class-instance - good answer with quote from standard

Comment: @pm100: Yes, it's a good Q&A. Unfortunately, a different one though.

Comment: @Deduplicator well it clarifies that the syntax is valid and quotes the spec. The spec does not say that the object pointer must be valid. Does that mean its UB, ie if the spec is silent is that UB

Comment: The biggest problem is maintainability.  It should be demo::f() and demo::a, and if someone later edits the code they might actually try to use that pointer.

Comment: ["Somebody told me that in basketball you can't hold the ball and run. I got a basketball and tried it and it worked just fine. He obviously didn't understand basketball."](http://c-faq.com/ansi/experiment.html)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Your example is well-defined. Merely dereferencing a null pointer is not invoking UB.

There is a lot of debate over this topic, which basically boils down to  whether indirection through a null pointer is itself UB.
The only questionable thing that happens in your example is the evaluation of the object expression. In particular, `d->a` is equivalent to `(*d).a` according to [expr.ref]/2:

> The expression `E1->E2` is converted to the equivalent form
>   `(*(E1)).E2`; the remainder of 5.2.5 will address only the first
>   option (dot).

`*d` is just evaluated:

> The postfix expression before the dot or arrow is evaluated;<sup>65</sup> the
>   result of that evaluation, together with the *id-expression*, determines
>   the result of the entire postfix expression.
>
> <sup>65) If the class member access expression is evaluated, the subexpression evaluation happens even if the result is unnecessary
>   to determine the value of the entire postfix expression, for example if the *id-expression* denotes a static member.</sup>

Let's extract the critical part of the code. Consider the expression statement

```
*d;
```

In this statement, `*d` is a discarded value expression according to [stmt.expr]. So `*d` is solely evaluated<sup>1</sup>, just as in `d->a`.
Hence if `*d;` is valid, or in other words the evaluation of the expression `*d`, so is your example.

### Does indirection through null pointers inherently result in undefined behavior?

There is the open CWG issue [**#232**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#232), created over fifteen years ago, which concerns this exact question. A very important argument is raised. The report starts with

> At least a couple of places in the IS state that indirection through a
>   null pointer produces undefined behavior: 1.9 [intro.execution]
>   paragraph 4 gives "dereferencing the null pointer" as an example of
>   undefined behavior, and 8.3.2 [dcl.ref] paragraph 4 (in a note) uses
>   this supposedly undefined behavior as justification for the
>   nonexistence of "null references."

Note that the example mentioned was changed to cover modifications of `const` objects instead, and the note in [dcl.ref] - while still existing - is not normative. The normative passage was removed to avoid commitment.

> However, 5.3.1 [expr.unary.op] paragraph 1, which describes the unary
>   "`*`" operator, does not say that the behavior is undefined if the
>   operand is a null pointer, as one might expect. Furthermore, at least
>   one passage gives dereferencing a null pointer well-defined behavior:
>   5.2.8 [expr.typeid] paragraph 2 says
>
> > If the lvalue expression is obtained by applying the unary * operator
> >     to a pointer and the pointer is a null pointer value (4.10
> >     [conv.ptr]), the typeid expression throws the bad_typeid exception
> >     (18.7.3 [bad.typeid]).
>
> This is inconsistent and should be cleaned up.

The last point is especially important. The quote in [expr.typeid] still exists and appertains to glvalues of polymorphic class type, which is the case in the following example:

```
int main() try {

    // Polymorphic type
    class A
    {
        virtual ~A(){}
    };

    typeid( *((A*)0) );

}
catch (std::bad_typeid)
{
    std::cerr << "bad_exception\n";
}
```

The behavior of this program is well-defined (an exception will be thrown and catched), and **the expression `*((A*)0)`  is evaluated** as it isn't part of an unevaluated operand. Now if indirection through null pointers induced UB, then the expression written as

```
*((A*)0);
```

would be doing just that, inducing UB, which seems nonsensical when compared to the `typeid` scenario. **If the above expression is merely evaluated as every discarded-value expression is<sup>1</sup>, where is the crucial difference that makes the evaluation in the second snippet UB?** There is no existing implementation that analyzes the `typeid`-operand, finds the innermost, corresponding dereference and surrounds its operand with a check - there would be a performance loss, too.

A note in that issue then ends the short discussion with:

> We agreed that the approach in the standard seems okay: **`p = 0; *p;`
>   is not inherently an error.** An lvalue-to-rvalue conversion would give
>   it undefined behavior.

I.e. the committee agreed upon this. Although the proposed resolution of this report, which introduced so-called "*empty lvalues*", was never adopted…

> However, “not modifiable” is a compile-time concept, while in fact
>   this deals with runtime values and thus should produce undefined
>   behavior instead. Also, there are other contexts in which lvalues can
>   occur, such as the left operand of . or .*, which should also be
>   restricted. Additional drafting is required.

…**that does not affect the rationale**. Then again, it should be noted that this issue even precedes C++03, which makes it less convincing while we approach C++17.

---

CWG-issue [**#315**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#315) seems to cover your case as well:

> Another instance to consider is that of invoking a member function
>   from a null pointer:
>
> ```
>   struct A { void f () { } };
>   int main ()
>   {
>     A* ap = 0;
>     ap->f ();
>   }
> ```
>
> […]
>
> Rationale (October 2003):
>
> **We agreed the example should be allowed. `p->f()` is rewritten as
>   `(*p).f()` according to 5.2.5 [expr.ref]. `*p` is not an error when
>   `p` is null unless the lvalue is converted to an rvalue (4.1
>   [conv.lval]), which it isn't here.**

According to this rationale, indirection through a null pointer per se does not invoke UB without further lvalue-to-rvalue conversions (=accesses to stored value), reference bindings, value computations or the like. (Nota bene: Calling a *non-static* member function with a null pointer should invoke UB, albeit merely hazily disallowed by [class.mfct.non-static]/2. The rationale is outdated in this respect.)

I.e. a mere evaluation of `*d` does not suffice to invoke UB. The identity of the object is not required, and neither is its previously stored value. On the other hand, e.g.

```
*p = 123;
```

is undefined since there is a value computation of the left operand, [expr.ass]/1:

> In all cases, the assignment is sequenced after **the value computation
>   of the right and left operands**

Because the left operand is expected to be a glvalue, the identity of the object referred to by that glvalue must be determined as mentioned by the definition of evaluation of an expression in [intro.execution]/12, which is impossible (and thus leads to UB).

---

<sup>1</sup> [expr]/11:

> In some contexts, an expression only appears for its side effects.
>   Such an expression is called a *discarded-value expression*. **The
>   expression is evaluated and its value is discarded.** […]. The lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) is
>   applied if and only if the expression is a glvalue of
>   volatile-qualified type and […]

Comment: It does not look as if that resolution ever made it into any standard. Probably because of what it would mean for references...

Comment: @Deduplicator Yeah, there were issues (no pun intended) with the resolutions. However, the conclusion drawn remains.

Comment: If you are aware that the resolution was never made law, then why quote it as if it was? Better find something which did, especially as that one is 13+ years old (two minor and one major standard in the interim).

Comment: @Deduplicator I didn't quote any resolutions. I quoted rationals.

Comment: @T.C.: Yes, an additional pointer to there being a huge construction site. No resolution for the issue at hand though, expecially none which made it into the standard ;-(

Comment: @Deduplicator ... but I mentioned reference bindings, even in the same sentence.

Comment: "Dereferencing a null pointer doesn't invoke UB without further lvalue-to-rvalue conversions (=accesses to stored value) or reference bindings" that's what some want, not what actually is. Happy with my extending the quote?

Comment: Reference binding is an odd case because there the standard definitely doesn't mean what it says. What it currently has ("A reference shall be initialized to refer to a valid object or function.") would require a diagnostic every time that rule is violated, which is obviously impractical.

Comment: @Columbo: As mentioned in my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28483477/6345, your CWG reference doesn't dispute that the above is UB.

Comment: "`*p` is not an error when p is null unless the lvalue is converted to an rvalue" - so `int *p = NULL; *p = 5;` is not an error?

Comment: @immibis The "unless" bit is not the only exception, I'm afraid, and this particular example was mentioned in chat. I added an explanation further down the answer which tries to settle this case.

Comment: *"The identity of the object is not required"* In the example of the OP or in the example of CWG 315?

Comment: @dyp In the example of the OP. But why would the identity be inherently required for a call to a member function? IMO an identity is necessary once e.g. a data member is accessed.

Comment: I do not know what exactly "identity" means in this context. However, I can imagine you need an address for the this-pointer parameter of the member function (from an implementation's point of view). After all, that member function could be defined in another TU. Consider `f().g()` -- we need to evaluate `f()` to get the identity of the object the object-expression refers to. Not that any of this would matter, since we know there's an unresolved defect.

Comment: Well, @Deduplicator, you have a point. I adjusted my answer. Do you think it's appropriate now?

Comment: The penultimate sentence of the discussion of CWG 232 is *"Also, there are other contexts in which lvalues can occur, such as the left operand of `.` or `.*`, which should also be restricted."*, whereas the rationale of CWG 315 states that this example should be well-formed. So either those two are contradicting, or there "is" a set of specific restriction that does not contain the example from CWG 315. It *seems* the committee thinks this issue has not been resolved (or they didn't update the status). I'm not sure what the implementers think (especially wrt UB optimizations).

Comment: @dyp So how about a "push"? E.g. via a thread in the discussion group?

Comment: Of course you can try that :) But I would guess that the committee rather favours discussions of actual problems. So, it would be nice if there was some convincing example that requires a resolution of this issue. (For example, [Richard Smith's lambda trick](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=20209), but it looks so much like a hack to me that it might not be convincing.) Edit: A lot of UB has become observable via constant expressions, and I think some of the UB optimizations have also been introduced since the last discussions of that topic.

Comment: "The behavior of this program is well-defined " yes, but not due to any general rule, but due to the specific and narrow exception for `typeid` you quoted.

Comment: @Deduplicator And that's exactly my argument. Why is it valid to perform indirection through a null pointer only if that expression is an operand of typeid? Note that both are evaluated, but I do mention that in my answer

Comment: Well, because the definition of typeid makes extra-provisions for exactly that case. Which means it is (unfortunately?) not generalizable. Anyway, I like it much better now.

Comment: @Deduplicator I think you missed the point I was trying to make. I am not using this to make conclusions about the general case. I am trying to point out inconsistencies just as Miller did. Btw., I'll mention this another time now: The operand is evaluated. If the evaluation does not invoke UB there, it cannot on its own, do you agree?

Comment: Yes, having an exception for `typeid` is certainly inconsistent. It just wasn't quite clear to me how you were arguing it there. Well, good job.

Comment: "Even calling a member function with *d as the object argument doesn't require" - mean to complete that sentence? Also, in the case of non-static member functions, [class.mfct.non-static]/p2 is relevant.

Comment: @T.C. [class.mfct.non-static]/p2 solely addresses object arguments that refer to some object. No object is associated with an 'empty lvalue'.  Or do you think that passage still carries some weight in this discussion?

Comment: @Columbo Well, it makes no sense to me that calling `f()` on a non-object isn't UB, but is UB on some object of the wrong type.

Comment: @T.C. It doesn't make sense to me that the object arguments value is of any importance if `this` is not odr-used. As long as the object argument itself is a valid expression, and not used inside the member function, I see no problem whatsoever.

Comment: @Columbo I think it's reasonable to permit implementations to diagnose calling a member function on a non-object (or object of the wrong type), even if `this` isn't odr-used, since that usually indicate some sort of programmer error.

Comment: @T.C. Well, an Implementation is allowed to diagnose anything with a warning. Or are you talking about constant expressions, where such calls should be disallowed by making them UB?

Comment: @Columbo It's technically impossible to diagnose such calls at compile time; making them UB allows them to be caught at run time using sanitizers. Not being able to use them in constant expressions is a nice bonus.

Comment: @T.C. Runtime sanitizers? Never heard of that. Good point though.

Comment: @Columbo Clang and GCC has a whole set of them. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html, search for `-fsanitize`.

Comment: @T.C. Whoops, totally forgot to answer, I apologize. Sanitizers are not standardized and thus allowed to diagnose anything, even well-defined statements (as long as they are inherently unreasonable - i.e. "insane"). Also, I agree that such an interpretation of [class.mfct.non-static]/p2 is inconsistent/nonsensical. However, I believe that paragraph should be removed, since aliasing is covered by §3.10 anyway, and there is no reason to restrict possible values of `this`.

Comment: @Columbo A sanitizer that turns well-defined code into errors is going to be pretty annoying IMO. Regardless, I see no reason why the standard shouldn't restrict it, if permitting it only allows "insane" code.

Comment: @T.C.: If everyone who thinks a construct has, or should have, defined behavior agrees what that behavior should be, that would suggest to me that the behavior should be defined unless doing so would impose non-trivial expense or create an actual problem.  The fact that some people may not see a use for it, or think the construct is meaningless, insane, distasteful, or whatever, is hardly a good reason to deny the construct to those who would find it useful.

Answer (score 4):

From the C++ Draft Standard N3337:

> **9.4 Static members**
>
> 2 A `static` member s of class `X` may be referred to using the *qualified-id expression* `X::s`; it is not necessary to use the class member access syntax (5.2.5) to refer to a `static` member. A `static` member may be referred
>   to using the class member access syntax, in which case the object expression is evaluated.

And in the section about object expression...

> **5.2.5 Class member access**
>
> 4 If E2 is declared to have type “reference to T,” then E1.E2 is an lvalue; the type of E1.E2 is T. Otherwise,
>   one of the following rules applies.
>
> — If `E2` is a `static` data member and the type of `E2` is `T`, then `E1.E2` is an lvalue; the expression designates the named member of the class. The type of `E1.E2` is T.

Based on the last paragraph of the standard, the expressions:

```
  d->fun();
  std::cout << d->a;
```

work because they both designate the named member of the class regardless of the value of `d`.

Comment: Where in those quotes does it allow `d` not to point to any object?

Comment: "If E2 is a static data member ... the expression designates the named member." It says it right there, and it makes sense because the pointer is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @KennyOstrom: I don't see any mandate to ignore UB invoked by the expression `E1` in that quote, sorry.

Comment: @Deduplicator Where in the standard does it actually say dereferencing a null pointer, by itself, *is* undefined behavior?

Comment: @Deduplicator, My understanding: `d->fun()` is converted to `(*d)->fun()`. However, that is only at compile time. The expression `(*d)` is never evaluated at run time since `d->fun()` is already resolved to `demo::fun()` at compile time.

Comment: @RSahu: If that was the case, they would have designated it as an "unevaluated context", which they explicitly did not.

Comment: @Deduplicator, could that be a defect of omission?

Comment: @RSahu: Making it unevaluated would open a humongous can of worms, because making a function static or not would drastically and unexpectedly change code, especially in templates. And allowing "empty lvalues" is something they didn't do because that would also have far-reaching unfortunate consequences.

Comment: @RSahu The LHS of `.` needs to be evaluated even if it's static, or `g().f()` might not evaluate `g()`.

Comment: Even though the expression designates the named member of the class, that doesn't "bypass" the evaluation of `E1` . A more stark example, `g()->a` where `g` divides by zero for example, and then returns a null pointer

Answer (score 4):

> runs fine and produces expected output instead of any runtime error.

That's a basic assumption error. What you are doing is **undefined behavior**, which means that your claim for **any kind** of "expected output" is faulty.

**Addendum:** Note that, while there is a CWG defect ([#315](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#315)) report that is closed as "in agreement" of *not* making the above UB, it relies on the positive closing of *another* CWG defect ([#232](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#232)) that is still active, and hence none of it is added to the standard.

Let me quote a part of a comment from [James McNellis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/151292/james-mcnellis) to [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2474021/6345) to a similar Stack Overflow question:

> I don't think CWG defect 315 is as "closed" as its presence on the "closed issues" page implies. The rationale says that it should be allowed because "*p is not an error when p is null unless the lvalue is converted to an rvalue." However, that relies on the concept of an "empty lvalue," which is part of the proposed resolution to CWG defect 232, but which has not been adopted.

Comment: @Columbo: Now if you would show that those resolutions ever made it into the standard, you would have a point.

Comment: @Columbo: I added a blurb addendum from James McNellis that clarifies why your answer doesn't dispute that it's UB.

Comment: Now this is the only correct answer. Shame I cannot upvote it again.

Comment: Is there any reason why a *quality* implementation should ever care about the instance in this scenario?  I suppose it might be fair to warn that code might get broken by compiler designers which take pride in finding "clever" ways to avoid making their compilers do anything not mandated by the Standard.  On the other hand, the Standard only defines a "conforming" implementation, rather than an "implementation whose usefulness isn't undermined by obtuseness"; the fact that an some particular behavior would be allowable by the former doesn't mean the latter could behave likewise.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing here is what I would consider an ill-conceived and unfortunate design choice in the specification of the C++ language and many other languages that belong to the same general family of programming languages.

These languages allow you to refer to static members of a class using a reference to an instance of the class.  The actual value of the instance reference is of course ignored, since no instance is required to access static members.

So, in `d->fun();` the the compiler uses the `d` pointer *only during compilation* to figure out that you are referring to a member of the `demo` class, and then it ignores it. No code is emitted by the compiler to dereference the pointer, so the fact that it is going to be NULL during runtime does not matter.

So, what you see happening is in perfect accordance to the specification of the language, and in my opinion the specification suffers in this respect, because it allows an illogical thing to happen: to use an instance reference to refer to a static member.

P.S. Most compilers in most languages are actually capable of issuing warnings for that kind of stuff.  I do not know about your compiler, but you might want to check, because the fact that you received no warning for doing what you did might mean that you do not have enough warnings enabled.

Comment: Your proposed change would possibly break existing code. `template <class T> f(T &t) { t.g(); } struct StillWorking { void g() {} }; struct NowBroken { static void g(); } }; f(StillWorking()); f(NowBroken());`

Comment: "It should be impossible to use an instance reference to refer to a static member." That ship has sailed a long, long time ago.

Comment: P.S.: I meant to write an example with `const&` (mine won't compile anyway), but the point stands.

Comment: @T.C. yes, it has sailed, but am I not entitled to have the opinion that it should never have been this way?

Comment: @ChristianHackl would you be satisfied if I had written "It should have been impossible" instead of "It should be impossible" ?

Comment: @MikeNakis: I'd still not be sure if such a restriction would be justified in the face of generic code like the one I posted (the kind of which is not uncommon with standard algorithm functors, e.g. `std::copy_if`) . P.S: FWIW, I did not downvote your answer.

Comment: A static member is still a member, so `this->foo` is OK whether it's a static member or non-static member. This is an intentional design choice, not a bug.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it now, I think I know what will please all you guys.  How about, if I replace "a bug in the specification" with "an ill-conceived and unfortunate design choice in the specification".  Yeah, that should get you covered.

Comment: Clear and concise answer to OP's question. +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

The expressions `d->fun` and `d->a()` both cause evaluation of `*d` ([expr.ref]/2).

The complete definition of the unary `*` operator from [expr.unary.op]/1 is:

> The unary `*` operator performs indirection: the expression to which it is applied shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a function type and the result is an lvalue referring to the object or function to which the expression points.

For the expression `d` there is no "object or function to which the expression points" . Therefore this paragraph does not define the behaviour of `*d`.

Hence the code is undefined by omission, since the behaviour of evaluating `*d` is not defined anywhere in the Standard.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat  That is correct but my answer depends on the text "the object or function to which the expression points"