# Invoke non-static methods of class by using NULL pointer : Undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++

Is it valid to call non-static methods using null pointer?  I have a below example which works perfectly fine.

```
#include <iostream>

class foo
{
public:
   void printMessage()
   {
      std::cout<<"Hello World";
   }
};

int main()
{
   foo *a = NULL;
   a->printMessage();
   return 0;
}
```

I also wanted to know, How it works? and, is it an example of undefined behaviour?

Comment: *"is it an example of undefined behaviour?"* - Yes

Comment: "Is it valid to call non-static methods using null pointer?" - No

Comment: it is defined that a->printMessage won't work tho

Comment: I believe there is a more detailed description here: [c++ access static members using null pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28482809/c-access-static-members-using-null-pointer) which deals with calling `static` and `non-static` member functions through a `nullptr`.