# Is using a null pointer to call a static member UB

Tags: c++, null, static-methods, undefined-behavior

Suppose I have the following:

```
struct f
{
    static int foo()
    {
        return 42;
    }
};


int main()
{
    f* x = 0;
    return x->foo();
}
```

Is it UB to do this?  I would argue that this is legal because I am not actually dereferencing the null pointer, only using its type info to call a static member function.....

Comment: @DeiDei I know ha, I changed it before the England game with Sweeden and there's apparently a 30 day waiting time before I can change it again :(

Comment: Unfortunately the accepted answer is wrong

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I think so too; do you agree that https://stackoverflow.com/a/28483477/4323 is more correct?  If so, what can be done to rectify this?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Yes and I don't know and I'm staying out of it because to be honest I'm equivocating a bit - your linked answer is very pedantic but gives us a way out, in this situation where the committee is almost universally against us. Personally I can't see how "dereferences the pointer to the object" can be considered well-defined when there isn't an object, and I'm not buying any of the "but I didn't convert the expression to an rvalue" rationales. I see no reason for `p = 0; *p;` to ever be valid. But, again, I am not in the majority there sadly :(