# C++ a class using other class

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I'm trying to define Node into NodeList class, And store it.

Whay I've tried is:

In *Try()* function, I defined a node like `Node *node = malloc...` This works fine. But if I use the node that I defined in class like `node = malloc...` this line gives runtime error. I don't understand what is the difference between these two.

Here are classes:

Node.hpp

```
#ifndef NODE_HPP
#define NODE_HPP

class Node{
public:
    int data;
};

#endif
```

Node.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Node.hpp"

using namespace std;
```

NodeList.hpp

```
#ifndef NODELIST_HPP
#define NODELIST_HPP

#include "Node.hpp"

class NodeList{
public:
    Node *node;
    void Try();
};

#endif
```

NodeList.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "NodeList.hpp"
#include "Node.hpp"

using namespace std;

void NodeList::Try(){
    //This works (doesn't give error):
    //Node *node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));

    //But I use the node I defined in class here and this line gives runtime error:
    node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "NodeList.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    NodeList *node = NULL;
    node->Try();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ***it gives error recipe for target failed*** It should give a more detailed error message than that.

Comment: `node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));` note that malloc does not call the constructors.

Comment: OP is invoking UB as far as i can see, by invoking Create from a null pointer

Comment: @drescherjm It's ok. I don't have any code in constructor now.

Comment: Related to the use of malloc in a `c++` program: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-and-or-new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-and-or-new)

Comment: @WARhead As I said above, in Try function I defined a Node and it was null. Used it to call Create and it worked. So I think it's not because it's null

Comment: @oburhesapbanyedi So, as far as I can see, it seems compiler allows call to functions that does not access any member variables, like it allows calls to static functions? ( which seems to be a contested topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28482809/c-access-static-members-using-null-pointer )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28483256/6459731 this answer goes on to explain that the specific case given by is allowed in some compilers, so implementation defined?

Comment: @WARhead You say it's contested but I have to call it like this. Because I'm trying to store Node into NodeList. So I define the Node in NodeList. And it's null at first.

Comment: You could make Create() a static member function `static Node *Create(Node*);` and avoid the issue completely by `Node* node = Node::Create();`

Comment: With this said I am not sure any of this is related to the error message, however I am still waiting for the exact text of the message as ***recipe for target failed*** provides no help in debugging or identifying the compile error.

Comment: @drescherjm yes if I define like `Node* node = NULL` and call Create, it works. But it doesn't store. I want to use Node I defined in class NodeList: `class NodeList{ Node *node}` I don't understand what is the difference between these two?

Comment: Then `node = Node::Create();` in `NodeList` after you make it a static member function.

Comment: `class NodeList{ Node *node}` node has no value.

Comment: @drescherjm whole error is: `makefile:7: recipe for target 'run' failed      mingw32-make: *** [run]  Error -1073741819`

Comment: `-1073741819` is `0xC0000005` which is access violation. Meaning the program crashed when it ran. It's not a build error. I assume you are using Visual Studio code and it is hiding this detail (that the problem was at runtime and not build time) from you.

Comment: actually it's NotePad++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code has many problems:

1. In `Main.cpp` you are dereferencing a NULL pointer: `node->DosyaOku();`, but node is NULL. This is an undefined behavior.
2. You have the same problem in `NodeList.cpp`
3. You are using a `malloc` in `Node.cpp` and you should probably want to use a `new` instead (read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-and-or-new)), and you should think how to `free`/`delete` that pointer.
4. The `Create` in `Node.cpp` has a parameter that is overwritten immediately, that looks like an error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In main.cpp, it works well. But in `Try()` function I use the node I defined in class and it doesn't work. I don't understand the difference between these two.

Comment: **You have the same problem in NodeList.cpp** this gives error. But in `main.cpp` it doesnt.

Comment: It's an undefined behavior in both cases. If "it seems to work" in main.cpp it doesn't mean that it is correct and would not crash the next line you add.

Comment: Unfortunately sometimes with Undefined Behavior broken code can appear to work.

Comment: When I looked at this code earlier I did not think about the passed node* to Create. You are correct about point #4 that it does not make sense if you pass by value then don't use and immediately set it to a different value.

Comment: @drescherjm I edited the question and not using nullptr to call function now. But still I cant use node as I want.

Comment: It's ok. I changed null definition to malloc in main.cpp and it works now. Thank you all