Can & (address-of-operator) ever return nullptr?
Sounds like a trivial question judging from typical usage of & operator, but is there a guarantee from the standard that address-of-operator cannot return nullptr when trying to get an address?

It may happen if one has a silly overload of operator&, e.g. struct foo  { foo* operator& ()  { return nullptr; }  };

If you had a null reference (which is undefined behaviour) then it could return null

related to the first comment, consider that there is also std::addressof which one should use if you want to be sure to get an address rather than whatever a silly overload may return. Are you asking whether the address of an object can be nullptr or about &x specifically?

Is this just curiosity, which is fine? Then please state so in the question. Otherwise please ask about the actual and underlying problem you have.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai specifically &x, it's just a question that arose in our code review. We obviously don't do weird operator& overloading, but wanted to make sure it's safe in basic cases

@Someprogrammerdude that's a real question, whether it's sane to check the returned pointer or not in our code base

if you ask about &x there is no need to consult the standard. The answer is trivial as explained in the first comment.

Thanks for the answers! Feel free to post them

weirdness is in the eye of the beholder ;). Once there is an overload you cannot be sure that the resulting pointer is the address of an object. Rather than checking the returned pointer you should use std::adressof when you want to be sure to get an address

If you consider low-level programming, you can run in a situation where you may need to deal with an object whose address coincides with the representation of the null pointer. For example, on certain CPU architectures, interrupt vectors are placed at address 0, which was also used to represent the null pointer. This means that a pointer may test equal to null, while not being semantically null.

For a non-overload silly operator&, the &x will never be null unless undefined behavior is involved (in which case, the code is ill-formed, all bets are off, any observed behavior is allowed).  if (&x == nullptr) return; will never trigger.

@AlanBirtles: You can pass around null lvalue references without undefined behavior, it's the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion where UB kicks in (and applying & does NOT cause lvalue-to-rvalue conversion)

@BenVoigt I'm just referring to the answers in the linked post, if you disagree with them you should add a new answer

@AlanBirtles: https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ref#note-2 is very relevant, but it doesn't rule out glvalues to null.  You are prevented from using them to bind a reference-typed variable, but they might still appear in an expression.  It also appears that this is something the Standard writers have been tightening up in newer revisions.

But see https://stackoverflow.com/q/76894031/103167

@ach "This means that a pointer may test equal to null, while not being semantically null.": I would assume that you can't use that as a pointer from C++ code then or you need some special compiler configuration to give it some sensible (implementation-specific) semantics. With usual configuration compilers will completely ignore that this is a possibility for optimization because it can't happen in standard C++.

@BenVoigt It has been clarified recently via defect report that null lvalues do not exist and that dereferencing a null pointer value is in itself UB even if the resulting lvalue is not used in any way. And binding a reference to such an lvalue was always UB, so "passing around" would be difficult. In particular &*((int*)0) which is valid in C is UB in C++.

@user17732522 Not sure why you think you cannot use such a pointer. Of course, you can. The C++ standard says that dereferencing a null pointer causes undefined behavior, but this simply means that the standard lays no requirement as to what effect such code may have. On a specific platform, though, it may have some well-defined effect, and the compiler vendors for that platform should accommodate that. And yes, this may restrict the optimization opportunities for the compiler.

@ach Yes, sure. I am just saying that common compilers like GCC, Clang and probably others will not accommodate for that in their default configurations. (And I don't know how one would be able to configure them to accommodate for it.)

@user17732522 There is no such thing as common compiler. Every specific compiler version targets a concrete platform and must adapt to the rules of that platform. I don't know if there are e. g. GCC and Clang version aiming 8086 MS-DOS, but, if there are, they must support such a use case.

There is no guarantee that the operator& can't return nullptr, for instance by overloading this operator.
Here is a contrived example:
#include <iostream>

struct foo  { foo* operator& ()  { return nullptr; }  };

int main()
{
    foo f;
    
    if (&f == nullptr) {  std::cout << "nullptr detected\n";  }
    
    std::cout << "the true address is " << std::addressof(f) << "\n";
}

Demo

It is a bit of a philosophical question whether an operator&() function is necessarily considered an "address of" operator.   The point of std::addressof() is obtaining the address of an object even in the presence of an overloaded operator&().

OP's question is specifically for &x (as OP mentioned in a comment).

Can & (address-of-operator) ever return nullptr?

No for built-in types and no for user defined types, if operator & is not overloaded. Otherwise, for user defined types, you can overload & operator and then the behavior will be based on your implementation of operator&, where you can return nullptr as well.
From C++17 (8.3.1)  Unary operators [emphasis mine]:

3 The result of the unary & operator is a pointer to its operand. The operand shall be an lvalue or a qualified-id.
If the operand is a qualified-id naming a non-static or variant member m of some class C with type T, the
result has type “pointer to member of class C of type T” and is a prvalue designating C::m. Otherwise, if
the type of the expression is T, the result has type “pointer to T” and is a prvalue that is the address of the
designated object (4.4) or a pointer to the designated function. [ Note: In particular, the address of an object
of type “cv T” is “pointer to cv T”, with the same cv-qualification. — end note ] For purposes of pointer
arithmetic (8.7) and comparison (8.9, 8.10), an object that is not an array element whose address is taken in
this way is considered to belong to an array with one element of type T.


EDIT:
Below part is to justify the claim that address of operator & cannot return nullptr for a user defined type operand (that does not have overloaded & operator).
Below references are from C++17.
From 7.11 Pointer conversions

1 A null pointer constant is an integer literal (5.13.2) with value zero or a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t. A
null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the null pointer value of that type and is
distinguishable from every other value of object pointer or function pointer type. ....

From 8.10 Equality operators

2 If at least one of the operands is a pointer, pointer conversions (7.11), function pointer conversions (7.13),
and qualification conversions (7.5) are performed on both operands to bring them to their composite pointer
type (Clause 8). Comparing pointers is defined as follows:
(2.1) — If one pointer represents the address of a complete object, and another pointer represents the address
one past the last element of a different complete object,88 the result of the comparison is unspecified.
(2.2) — Otherwise, if the pointers are both null, both point to the same function, or both represent the same
address (6.9.2), they compare equal.
(2.3) — Otherwise, the pointers compare unequal.

   A *obj1 = nullptr;
   A obj2;

It is guaranteed that the expression obj1 == &obj2 will evaluate to false.

The quote, by itself, doesn't prohibit to return nullptr. ach comment seems to suggest that it is even possible.

It's nice to quote the standard, but you're missing something - is there a guarantee that no variables or functions will be located at the address used for nullptr?  I think most compilers would avoid that situation even if the spec allows it, but that's not the question.

@Jarod42 Yes, I agree. I believe, here we should check what standard says about nullptr - 7.11 1. A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the null pointer value of that type and is distinguishable from every other value of object pointer or function pointer type. C++ standard lib uses nullptr to indicate failures, for e.g. - 21.6.2.1 9 [Example: T* p2 = new(nothrow) T; // returns nullptr if it fails. Like this there are so many other examples. Assume on a system you have address of operator which is returning nullptr, Isn't it going against lang std?

@MarkRansom: Yes, there is such a guarantee.  Every null pointer, including those implicitly converted from nullptr, compares unequal to the address of any actual object.  https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.eq#3  Although, you've phrased it wrong... "the address used for nullptr" is a contradiction.  Null pointers do not represent any address, according to the Standard.  They have to have some bit pattern stored, yes, but formally that bit pattern is not an address at all.

@BenVoigt thanks.  That sounds worthy of its own answer.
